# Dynamically spread setState doesn't work on ternary operator spread

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested state like this:

```
this.state = {
  fields: {
    subject: '',
    from: {
      name: '',
    },
  },
};
```

In an `onChange` function I'm handling updates to these nested values.

I'm trying to build a dynamically spread `setState()` for deep nests using dot notation.

For instance, with the array: `const tree = ['fields','subject']` I'm able to update the `subject` state value with:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  [tree[0]]: {
    ...prevState[tree[0]],
    ...(tree[2] ? {
      ...prevState[tree[1]],
      [tree[2]]: value
    } 
    : { [tree[1]]: value })
  },
}));
```

Since the ternary operator is ending on `{ [tree[1]]: value }`

But when my `tree` array is: `const tree = ['fields','from','name']` the state value for `fields.from.name` is not changing, where it should be resolving to the first part of the ternary operator:

```
{
  ...prevState[tree[1]],
  [tree[2]]: value
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Isn't that link more about accessors than mutators?

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Yes, it just shows the basic concept of following a path (including recursion). That's why I just flagged it as "related."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've grown to prefer using libraries for these sorts of functions when it otherwise feels like I'm reinventing the wheel. [lodash](https://lodash.com/) provides a `set` function (which also supports string paths):

[`_.set(object, path, value`)](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set)

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
console.log(object.a[0].b.c);
// => 4

_.set(object, ['x', '0', 'y', 'z'], 5);
console.log(object.x[0].y.z);
// => 5
```

You'd also want to use [`_.cloneDeep(value)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep) because `_.set` mutates the object.

```
this.state = {
  fields: {
    subject: '',
    from: { name: '' },
  },
};


const tree = ['fields', 'from', 'name']; // or 'fields.from.name'
this.setState(prevState => {
  const prevState_ = _.cloneDeep(prevState);
  return _.set(prevState_, tree, value);
});
```

Comment: Using pre-made, pre-tested functionality is good, though the deep clone is more costly than only cloning what changes...

Comment: this isn't updating the state

Comment: To that end, something like Ramda's [`lensPath`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensPath) together with [`set`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#set) makes for a useful combination that only mutates what is necessary in such a set.  But it is only good for when you want to replace the whole state object with a minimally-mutated version.  Ramda won't mutate your data for you.  ([`assocPath`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath) is also helpful.)

Comment: @alyx - I fixed a typo and added `return` to my function in `setState`.

Comment: @Wex - FWIW, I find it really handy to do a Stack Snippet so I catch it when I make those kinds of mistakes. (You probably know how, but if not, [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).)

Comment: Thanks T.J. I'll use that next time.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a loop. For instance:

```
function update(prevState, tree, value) {
    const newState = {};
    let obj = newState;
    for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; ++i) {
        const name = tree[i];
        if (i === tree.length - 1) {
          obj[name] = value;
        } else {
          obj = obj[name] = {...prevState[name]};
        }
    }
    return newState;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
this.state = {
  fields: {
    subject: '',
    from: {
      name: '',
    },
  },
};

function update(prevState, tree, value) {
    const newState = {};
    let obj = newState;
    let prev = prevState;
    for (let i = 0; i < tree.length; ++i) {
        const name = tree[i];
        if (i === tree.length - 1) {
          obj[name] = value;
        } else {
          const nextPrev = prev[name];
          obj = obj[name] = {...nextPrev};
          prev = nextPrev;
        }
    }
    return newState;
}

const tree = ['fields','from','name']
const value = "updated";
console.log(update(this.state, tree, value));
```

I'm sure that can be shoehorned into a call to `Array#reduce` (because any array operation can be), but it wouldn't buy you anything.